# Operator which takes an argument and maps onto another operator, is it formally possible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, operator-theory

Let $\circ$ and $\Phi$ be functions $\circ:x\rightarrow x, \Phi: x\rightarrow x^2$.

Then let's define operators $\circ, \Phi$ which map onto operators and take an argument $\circ(x):A\times B\rightarrow xA \circ xB$ and $\Phi(x):A\times B\rightarrow xA\Phi(\Phi(xB))$.

We supply each time the argument $2$ to each operator such that: $a\Phi b\rightarrow 2a\Phi4b^2\rightarrow4a\Phi64b^4...$, $a\circ b\rightarrow 2a\circ 2b\rightarrow 4a\circ4b...$

Is there a formal way of defining this?

Comment: The grammar of your question doesn't quite make sense: you start off by saying that $\circ$ and $\Phi$ are functions on some set, but then in the definitions of the operators (by the same names), you're assuming that the original functions are acting on a Cartesian product of that set with itself. I think the question almost makes sense if the first line is removed entirely; what did you intend by it? (Also, is 64 correct? Why isn't it 16?)

Comment: I was hesitating to clarify this when posting the question, so I mean that $\circ, \Phi$ can be read both as a function or as an operator depending on the context. Since we supply 2 as an argument to the $\Phi$-operator we get $2a\Phi4b^2\rightarrow 2*2a\Phi(\Phi(2*4b^2))$ since $\Phi(2*4b^2)=(8b^2)^2=64b^4$ we get $2a\Phi4b^2\rightarrow 4a\Phi 64b^4$.

Comment: Yes, I did understand that. I don't understand what $2a\Phi 4b^2$ is supposed to mean: is this just an odd way of writing an ordered pair? Or do you mean that $\Phi$ is supposed to be operating on $2a$ and $4b^2$. If the latter, why did you write arrows in your chains, instead of equals signs?

Comment: So we could write this as $a\Phi b(2)=2a\Phi 4b^2$, or $x\Phi x(1)=x\Phi x^2$. Does this answer your question? So the $\rightarrow$-chain would be equivalent to $f\rightarrow g\rightarrow h$ where $f,g,h$ would be functions.

Comment: Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my best guess at what you might be looking for: Recall that for sets $U$ and $V$, the notation $V^U$ means the set of all functions $U\to V$. Then define $$\widetilde\Phi:\Bbb N\to (A\times B)^{A\times B}$$
$$\widetilde\Phi: n\mapsto \Big[(a,b)\mapsto (na,\Phi(nb))\Big]$$
and then your $\Phi$-chain is then obtained by taking iterated compositions of $\widetilde\Phi(2)$:
$$(a,b)\to\widetilde\Phi(2)(a,b)\to\left(\widetilde\Phi(2)\circ\widetilde\Phi(2)\right)(a,b)$$

Similarly we may define $\widetilde\circ$.